# Finding &nbsp character using Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have a web page that have been generated from a Word document (using save as from the word doc). It has generated some &nbsp characters.

Initially, I am using a Regex function to look for "2 General" within the generated HTML text. Here is a snippet where "2 General" is located:

`<span style="font-size:9.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial Black&quot;,sans-serif">2<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;</span>General<o:p></o:p></span>")`

This is the python code I used:

```
el1_search = "2 General"
el1_search = re.compile(el1_search.replace(' ', '[\s\u00A0]*'))
el1 = soup.find(text=el1_search)
```

The el1_search will then be replaced by a user input. (I think that) I do not have the option to find and replace the \u00A0 characters because I want to output the soup with modifications based on this search.

The user will then be able to make specific searches within the text. The results will then be used to wrap the parent table element in div with special attributes.

I do not seem to be able to find the element with the \u00A0 element. Can you kindly help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BeautifulSoup`'s method `.get_text()` to get the string (it will handle automatically `&nbsp;` etc.. for you).

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<span style="font-size:9.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial Black&quot;,sans-serif">2<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;</span>General<o:p></o:p></span>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find('span').get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))
```

Prints:

```
2 General
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will clarify my question - the HTML is part of a larger document, with a lot more spans, so I will need to look for the specific text. Also, the "2 General" will then be replaced by a user input

Comment: @Jason You can use CSS selectors and/or BeautifulSoup's own api to locate specific tag. Then you can use, for example, [`replace_with()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) to replace the text.

Comment: Thanks Andrej. This will not work - I need the user to make the text input, then I will look for the element, to then find the parent table element. I added a modification to my question